# Difference between the 2 Socket.EndReceive functions

Tags: c#, sockets

I can't tell from the documentation what the difference between these two is:

[Socket.EndReceive Method (IAsyncResult, SocketError)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145145(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Socket.EndReceive Method (IAsyncResult)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Does the first one output errors while the second one throws?

**EDIT:**

To be more specific:  The output param will be bogus if an error is thrown.  That suggests the SocketError version doesn't throw errors.  Yet it says it throws the same error *classes*.  Does that mean mean it throws all the same *errors*?  Maybe there are errors that occur but don't get thrown.  Maybe you need to use this function to get all errors.  Do I need two sets of error handling - one for the throw and one for the output param?  Is one function preferred over the other?

Comment: That's how it implemented in .net core https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/2117bae3a6c9736033e6d1659821ff3a1069920b/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs#L3722. And in the windows .net  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,4485

Comment: _"I can't tell from the documentation what the difference"_ -- why not? What _specifically_ is it that the documentation seems unclear about.  Note that both throw the same exceptions, including `SocketException`. So it _can't_ be that one doesn't throw exceptions. From the documentation, it seems clear to me that one method just provides a convenient mechanism to retrieve the error code directly. Personally, I think this is superfluous, since you'll always get an exception if the error code is non-success and the code is easily retrieved from the exception object. But it is what it is.

Comment: A socket operation can easily fail, network connections are not that reliable.  So if you call EndReceive(IAsyncResult) then you can easily get a SocketException, you need to catch it.  If you don't want that exception then use the 2nd overload, it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs both of them behave the same. The only difference is the extra param when doing error handling.

Based on the note

> If you receive a SocketException, use the SocketException.ErrorCode property to obtain the specific error code. After you have obtained this code, refer to the Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation in the MSDN library for a detailed description of the error.

It seems that you can use the [`SocketError` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketerror(v=vs.110).aspx) object passed as reference on  `Socket.EndReceive Method (IAsyncResult, SocketError)` to get information about what went wrong without the need to check *Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation*

Comment: If it throws an error, would that ref param be undefined?

Comment: @johnnycrash It should not